# How do I divide my Rust code between two source files?

Tags: module, include, rust

Updated in response to "possible duplicate"

Yes, the indicated question, ["Can't understand Rust module system"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610079) solved my problem, for which my thanks.

However, as part of my question, I also asked for pointers into the documentation "where I missed this"; it would be nice to have an answer to that, too, even if the answer is "it's not explained simply". (which is OK - I appreciate there's lots of work done and to do.)

---

I'm starting to learn Rust, from a background of z/Assembler, Python, Go, and some C; but no C++ or Java.

I've successfully built and executed the "Hello World!" example, and a couple of other monolithic `main.rs`. For one of these, I've tried to separate my utility functions into a separate source file, but I can't get it to build, and I confess I find the documentation a bit incomprehensible. (All due respect to the authors; I'm sure it's me.)

So for a minimum non-working example, I went back to hallo world.

In my src/ directory, I have two files:

say.rs:

```
mod say {
    pub fn say() {
        println!("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

main.rs:

```
pub mod say;
fn main() {
    say();
}
```

`cargo build` gives me this error message:

```
D:\Development\Rust\hw\src>cargo build
   Compiling hw v0.1.0 (file:///D:/Development/Rust/hw)
main.rs:3:5: 3:8 error: unresolved name `say` [E0425]
main.rs:3     say();
              ^~~
```

etc. I've also tried calling as `say::say()`, but with the same answer.

I've come to the conclusion that I'm missing something pretty fundamental here. Could someone please explain where I've gone wrong, and, hopefully, give a pointer into the book where I should have seen this?

Comment: RE your edit (which I almost missed, a comment reply would have been better): http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html#multiple-file-crates splits up a single-file module into multiple files

Comment: *I also asked for pointers into the documentation* — "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)". It may be more appropriate to ask on the [User's Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/) or the [Rust Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust).